# What does this javascript syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am trying to understand a script generated by Asp.Net Ajax Toolkit, which is currently giving an "object expected" (error goes away if I place my PopupControlExtender in an update panel).

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ValidationSummary1').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_ValidationSummaries, document.getElementById('ctl00_ValidationSummary1'));
}
(function() {var fn = function() {AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupBehavior.invokeViaServer('ctl00_c1_componentCategoryListUC_componentCategoryGrid_modalPopupExtender', true); Sys.Application.remove_load(fn);};Sys.Application.add_load(fn);})();
```

What I see here is:

```
someobject.someevent = function() {
    dosth;
} /* Get ready, I am about to do sth crazy ... */
(function() { dosth; })(); /* you did what? */
```

What does this syntax mean?

**Edit:** I am specifically curious about (function () { ... })() coming immediately after another function's ending }.

**Edit:** Turns out, ajax guys forgot to place a semicolon after the event handler assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The

```
(function() { dosth; })();
```

syntax declares an anonymous function, and then executes it immediately.  It's equivalent to doing this:

```
 var myFun = (function() { dosth; });
 myFun();
```

but without the temporary variable.

Broadly speaking this is similar to just executing whatever `dosth` is; but creating a function object introduces a new scope for variables (due to the closure), and thus this is often used to work around issues with scoping.

In the specific case you've quoted, I don't see any reason why this would be particularly necessary.  However it could be done like this for two reasons - either the final Javascript itself is generated by some automatic process that can't tell whether the closure is needed; or it was written by a human who decided to always wrap things in functions to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function() { dosth; })();
```

Here, an anonymous function is created, and then immediately invoked.

This is a relatively popular idiom to create a local scope in JavaScript, where only functions get their own scope.

A local scope allows you to have private variables and avoids name clashes.

In other languages you could write something like

```
int a = 1;
{
   int b = 0;
   if (something){
       int c = 3;
   }
}
```

and the three variables would all be in separate scopes, but in JavaScript you have to 
declare a function to get a new scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() { dosth; })();
```

wraps dosth in an anonymous function and then runs that anonymous function as soon as the page loads (that's what those final ()'s do)

Comment: It actually runs immediately. This could be before the page is finished loading

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean this:

```
(function() { dosth; })(); /* you did what? */
```

This declares an anonymous function in the first parens block which will be a returned object from that paren block executed by the second paren block.

So this defines and executes whatever "dosth" is.