# how this function work and how i can pass parameter that is param_url

Tags: javascript

below is function i want to use

```
(function () {
  var url = param_url;
})(); // what are these ending curly brackets for ?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this javascript syntax mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511096/what-does-this-javascript-syntax-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ending parentheses (`()`) call the function. You can pass arguments to it by putting them within the parentheses.

What you have there is a *function expression* which is then immediately called. The function expression is:

```
(function () { var url = param_url; })
```

...and then the parens call it. it's the same as:

```
var v = function () { var url = param_url; };
v();
```

...aside from the use of `v`, of course. So to pass an argument to it, just do this:

```
(function (argname) { var url = param_url; })(your_argument_here);
```

[kangax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax) has written up a [useful article](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/) on function expressions, including browser bugs related to naming the function in the expression (amongst other things), which you *should* be able to but sadly, can't currently.