# What does this syntax mean? (function () {//code})()

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do parentheses surrounding a JavaScript object/function/class declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-m)
>   [What does this javascript syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511096/what-does-this-javascript-syntax-mean)
>   [What does this “(function(){});”, a function inside brackets, mean in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043647/what-does-this-function-a-function-inside-brackets-mean-in-javascript)

In the below code the anonymous function is being executed.

```
var a= 1;
var b =2;           
(function() {  
    var b = 3;  
    a += b;  
})();  
document.write(a + " "+ b);
```

1) What does putting parenthesis around the function definition do?

2) What does putting `()` after the closing parenthesis do?

Comment: Read this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593509/javascript-syntax-function-calls-and-using-parenthesis

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the `()` around the `function() { ... }` makes it an expression vs. a statement.  Because it's an expression which produces a function value the `()` at the end invoke the produced function.

Consider the alternatives

```
function () { 
  var b = 3;
  a += b;
}();
```

This produces a syntax error as the `()` are essentially trying to invoke a statement.

```
(function () {
  var b = 3;
  a += b;
});
```

This produces a `function` object which is never invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Well you say it in the first line, the code creates an anonymous function then executes it with no arguments (the trailing parenthesis)

Comment: Don't know why yours was given a down vote without any comments as your answer looks valid in my non-expert Javascript opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It a function executes it self,if you want to create an scope(or define local varible),because javascript has no block scope,a function is needed.

Answer (score 0):

ok, Your first question answer is just covering the hole function.without it function will executed and the second one is an anonymous function with no arguments.